# wp_dropdown_categories wordpress not working for multiple select

Tags: wordpress

How to select multiple category with  wp_dropdown_categories , it only allows single category to select.

```
<p class="<?php if (get_option('jr_submit_cat_required')!=='yes') : echo 'optional'; endif; ?>"      <label for="job_cat"><?php _e('Job Category', 'appthemes'); ?> <?php if (get_option('jr_submit_cat_required')=='yes') : ?><span title="required">*</span><?php endif; ?></label> <?php
            $sel = 0;
            if (isset($posted['job_term_cat']) && $posted['job_term_cat']>0) $sel = $posted['job_term_cat'];
            global $featured_job_cat_id;
            $args = array(
                'orderby'            => 'name',
                'exclude'            => $featured_job_cat_id,
                'order'              => 'ASC',
                'name'               => 'job_term_cat',
                'hierarchical'       => 0,
                'echo'               => 0,
                'class'              => 'chzn-select',
                'selected'           => $sel,
                'taxonomy'           => 'job_cat',
                'hide_empty'         => false
            );
            $dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( $args);
            $dropdown = str_replace( 'class=\'job_cat\' \'chzn-select\'>', 'class=\'job_cat\' \'chzn-select\'><option value="">'.__('Select a category&hellip;', 'appthemes').'</option>',$dropdown);
            echo $dropdown;
        ?></p>
```

I was to use it as a multiple select. i have try every way i can imagine entering it in the str_replace, with no luck. I know this cant possibly be as difficult as im making it, id really appreciate any help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace str_replace with preg_replace.

```
  $dropdown = preg_replace( 'class=\'job_cat\' \'chzn-select\'>', 'class=\'job_cat\' \'chzn-select\'><option value="">'.__('Select a category&hellip;', 'appthemes').'</option>',$dropdown);
```